# Divide the value anong others if is lesser then Max by eliminating the least user

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I am trying to find the least user whose value on value_votes class is lesser then all users by using the value of user class as a id for value_votes class in each condition and divide that value to other users who are remaining until the the max value is reached  by eliminating each user and then using the formula is the value_votes of least user is divided by the remaining users count in else condition

```javascript
localStorage.setItem('max_value','6');
    $(".users").each(function () {
        var users_id = $(this).val();
    var User_Vote_count = $('#'+users_id+'').val();

    var max_value = localStorage.getItem('max_value');

    if (User_Vote_count > max_value) {

        alert(users_id);
    } else if(User_Vote_count == max_value) {
             alert(users_id);
    }
});
```

HTML

```html
<input type="text" value="A9AH98" class="users">
<input type="text" value="16B9BH" class="users">
<input type="text" value="CC9GHF" class="users">
<input type="text" value="A9D9G5" class="users">

<input type="text" class="value_votes" id="A9AH98" value="3">
<input type="text" class="value_votes" id="16B9BH" value="1">
<input type="text" class="value_votes" id="CC9GHF" value="4">
<input type="text" class="value_votes" id="A9D9G5" value="5">
```

Comment: Pun,ctu ati. on h el ps read-abili.ty

Comment: Its very much unclear what you want to do...

Comment: @Shaik, so what's the problem? could you please provide some formula or pseudo code of your algorithm.

Comment: @Fahad sorry for the complication 1.find the least value in the `value_votes` class and divide that value to others using the formula is example now `value_votes` last value is `1` in textbox `16B9BH` i want to divide the value `1` to remaining textboxs that are `A9AH98`,`CC9GHF`,`A9D9G5` to divide the formula is value of least text box  `16B9BH`  this value `1` other text box count that is the remaining text box count is 3

Comment: point 2. is to check if the remaing 3 textbox have reached max value if yes alert that text box id else as now we have elmaneted the textbox `16B9BH` though it dint reach now we have to find the last value amone the remaining others that are this `A9AH98`,`CC9GHF`,`A9D9G5` three and repeat same as above untill the max vale is reached or a single text box is left out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in jsfiddle I'm posting code here:

```
localStorage.setItem('max_value','6');

var minValue;
var minItem;

//searching for minimum value among value inputs
$(".value").each(function() {
    var val = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    if (val && (!minItem || val < minValue)) {
        minItem = this;
        minValue = val;
    }
});

var minValId = $(minItem).attr("id");
console.log(minValId);

//searching for .user textboxes where value is not equal
var remainingUserElements = $("input.users:not([value='"+minValId+"'])");
console.log(remainingValueElements);

//searching for .value textboxes where id is not equal
var remainingValueElements = $("input.value:not([id='"+minValId+"'])");
console.log(remainingUserElements);

var maxValue = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('max_value'), 10);
console.log(maxValue);

//searching for .value elements where id is >= maxValue  
var geValueElements = remainingValueElements.filter(function(){
    return parseInt($(this).val(), 10) >= maxValue;
});

geValueElements.each(function(){
    //printing all values that are greater or equal to maxValue
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: if you dont mind can you join me hear http://jsfiddle.net/chsgf50t/25/#&togetherjs=NKU1UjlvDK